# MAGMA library: difference between magma_dgemm and magmablas_dgemm

Tags: c++, gpu, linear-algebra, blas, magma

In the most recent magma linear algebra library (version 1.6.1), http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/software/, in the testing code exercising dgemm functionality (source code: testing_dgemm.cpp), there was a call to functions `magma_dgemm` and `magmablas_dgemm`. Can someone clarify the difference between the two? Which one is more general (not tied to just GPU)?

Wirawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inspection of the source code reveals that `magmablas_Xgemm` is actually a C function that launches an appropriate `gemm` kernel on the GPU. Thus `magmablas_Xgemm` *is* a GPU-specific routine. On the other hand, `magma_Xgemm` is intended to be accelerator-agnostic routine that (currently) can be used for either GPU (NVIDIA/AMD, ...) or MIC.

Ref files, relative to MAGMA source directory (the CUDA edition):

```
./magmablas/dgemm_fermi.cu
./interface_cuda/blas_d.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically MAGMA includes gemm, both magma_*gemm that wraps cublas*gemm, and magmablas_*gemm that is Magma's open-source implementation.